# Efficient/feasible sparse matrix inversion in R

Tags: r, sparse, matrix-inverse

I am looking to perform a 2-stage least-squares estimation with sparse matrices in R, in the style of Bramoulle et al (J. Econometrics 2009). Specifically, let:

G be a **very sparse block-diagonal** matrix, roughly 63,000 x 63,000

X be a design matrix, not sparse but full of dummy variables (with the relevant excluded variables to avoid the obvious collinearity problem), 63,000 x 16

y be a vector of outcomes, 63,000 x 1

The analysis has me calculating a number of the standard X(X'X)^-1 X' regression operations. For example, define S to be 3 horizontally appended sparse matrices (so S is 63,000 x 48):

S=[(I-G)X,  (I-G)GX, (I-G)G^2 X]

P=S (S'S)^-1 S'

For simplicity, I want to perform the following calculation:

estimate = (X'PX)^-1 X' Py

I've been trying to use the '**Matrix**' package to perform the relevant inversions directly (particularly the S'S inversion in calculating P), and have been running into memory issues:

```
P=S %*% solve(t(S) %*% S) %*% t(S)
Error in LU.dgC(a) : cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)
```

I can obviously increase the memory allowed, but that only helps to a point.

My question is: are there best practices to exploit the structure of the problem? For example

1) I tried running `solve(t(S) %*% S, t(S))` to try to 'avoid' inverting, but got the same error message as above (out of memory)

2) S'S is symmetric, so doesn't this mean we can use the Cholesky decomposition? I tried and got an error:

```
chol2inv(chol(t(S)%*%S))
Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file ../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431
Error in chol2inv(chol(t(S) %*% S)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'chol2inv': Error in .local(x, ...) : 
  internal_chm_factor: Cholesky factorization failed
```

This is a bit strange since by construction S'S is symmetric.

I must admit I'm not the most well-versed in best-practices on inverting matrices in R, so any suggestions are welcome (also any other packages that might be better suited). Unfortunately I cannot provide a reproducible example as the data I'm using is protected.

Comment: having protected data doesn't/shouldn't mean you can't provide a reproducible example ... make up some data that looks like yours.  If it doesn't produce the same error, you have a clue that your data has special structure. If it does, you've got a reproducible example.

Comment: **Stop!** Whenever you see a matrix inverse $A^{-1}$ times something, that **DOES NOT** mean you should form the inverse. Instead, solve the linear system.

Comment: @MatthewGunn Right, I'm trying to avoid direct inversion, but doing a two-argument solve doesn't work either. Unless you had something else in mind?

Comment: Glancing at this so far, the full matrix G should *never* be formed explicitly. Your problem actually isn't that large. I don't have time to solve it, but you shouldn't have to form large matrices. If you use sparse matrices, you have to be incredibly careful to only call functions etc... that preserve sparsity, utilize the sparsity. You do anything that "fills" out the 63,000 by 63,000 matrix and you're triggering an event that requires 29 Gigabytes of memory.

Comment: True, since G is block diagonal I could essentially solve the problem for each block, which should be a lot more feasible . I'll probably start on that right away, but I'd still be interested in hearing about ways to 'get around' inverting to solve a system

Comment: Whenever you see $A^{-1}b$ you instead want to solve the linear system $Ax = b$. In some sense, you really have a programming problem here. One overall question is whether you want to use "sparse" matrices. Using a sparse matrix, you can form G. You have to be incredibly careful though to only call functions that preserve sparsity and utilize the sparsity.  Alternatively, you can break down the algorithm yourself, represent G as a list of matrices or something. I don't know what's better, but this is a programming problem...

Comment: Just to be explicit, your only hope of forming $G$ and $S$ is using the [sparse matrix datatype](http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2011/10/31/using-sparse-matrices-in-r/). Forming a regular 63000x63000 matrix = *death*. (Or alternatively, dive into the math and figure out a way to avoid forming G and S entirely.)

Comment: @Matthew That's how I have interpreted this question: a request to do that math (or otherwise find some suitable algorithm).  But Ray, how could we possibly suggest such improvements without having the details about the structure of your matrix?

Comment: @whuber Point taken. I'll try to cook up an example; in the meantime I'm going to try to solve the problem block-by-block (since the nasty P matrix is based off X multiplied by block-diagonal matrices). I'm mostly trying to figure out if I'm missing something really obvious in coding practices or the 'Matrix' package, analogous to failing to properly vectorize an operation in R

Comment: I am sympathetic.  I solved a problem like this recently and it was almost this large, too.  After a day of working at it, exploring various algorithms, I finally found a solution that fit into available RAM and was fast.  In the end it required all of eight lines of `R` code (which mostly manipulated arrays with four indexes each: the trick to vectorization often is getting the right numbers into exactly the right places).

Comment: Also if this would make more sense in say a programming section, then feel free to move it (new user, not sure how to do that).